# HTML5 Video and HTML5 Boilerplate

Tags: html, video, boilerplate

I'm trying to implement videoJS in the HTML5 Boilerplate. I've tried pasting the embed code suggested by videoJS but the results don't work. When the page loads the "poster" image appears but the loading wheel never stops and the video never plays.

I've tried including this in the header and footer to get the video started, but it hasn't worked:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var pElement = document.getElementById("#vid");

pElement.play();
};
</script>
```

I've also included all the video.js ref links in the header:

```
  <!-- Link to Video JS Library -->
  <script src="js/mylibs/video.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/video-js.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Video JS" charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  // Add VideoJS to all video tags on the page when the DOM is ready
    VideoJS.setupAllWhenReady();
  </script>
```

Does anyone have an example of good HTML5 video implementation with the HTML5 Boilerplate template. Admittedly I'm a noob so I apologize if this question seems kind of daft.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not be including them in <head> and footer. You should just include that script you pasted at the beginning at the bottom after that video.js ref links set of scripts.

You can always paste your code at http://jsfiddle.net and ask again so it can be fixed more quickly.